# how to calculate depth of object in image captured by android camera

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image captured by android camera. Is it possible to calculate depth of object in the image ? Image contains object and background only. Any suggestion, explanation or links that you think can help me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) is the library you need.

I did some depth identification of water levels in pure white background a few days ago.  Generally, if you want to identify the depth, you can convert the question to identify the edge of the changing colors.  In this case, you can convert the colorful pictures to grey and identify the changing of while-black-grey interface. OpenCV is capable of doing the job at high speed.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need further help.

Edits:

If you want to find the actual depths, you need to project the coordinate system of your pictures to the real world, or vice versa.  To do it, you have to know a fix location as your reference and the relationship between pixels and real distances.

What I did is find the fixed location and set it as zero.  Afterwards, I measured a length of an object in the picture, and also calculated the pixel amount of the object.  Therefore I obtained the relationship between pixels and real distances.

Note that these procedures may involve errors in the identification. I did it very carefully and the error was acceptable in my case.

Comment: Is it possible to find distance between the level of various depth ?

Comment: @Sagar Yes, of course.  I add some edits regarding depth.

Answer (score 0):

With only one image, accurate depth estimation is near impossible. However, there are various methods of estimating depth under certain assumptions or the availability of the camera calibration matrix. As mentioned by @WenlongLiu, OpenCV is a very good place to start with.